# Android ListView if statement

Tags: java, android, string, listview, if-statement

Hi i have the following ListView code:

```
    {
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,matches));
    }
```

I would like a listener which when it finds the string "start" from wordsList it does a if statement, I have tried for the past many hours but cannot get anywhere.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, could you please elaborate / rephrase?

Comment: Once the wordsList gets populated with strings i would like to read the strings and if one matches "start" i would like to do a if statement.

Comment: So you should create your own adapter. You would be able to do something on the "getView" method, if the argument is the right string.

Comment: wish i could get my head round on how to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      if (myList.getAdapter().getItem(position).equals("Start")) {
        //Do your stuff here
      }
  }
});
```

In that case, the listener will be called when the user clicks on the item which text is "Start". Is that what you want?